# Possible to add background effects to Microsoft Communication Services

Tags: sdk, microsoft-teams, azure-communication-services

I am wondering if it is possible to add the background effects to Microsoft Azure Communication Services just like in Teams itself. I am creating an API build and would automatically like to blur the background of the video. Is it possible? If so, where can I find the info to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of this post from April the feature is (or was) not supported yet:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/356360/how-to-settings-virtual-background-when-call.html